# Caused by: com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.MissingTableMapEventException: No TableMapEventData has been found for table id:137

Tags: mysql, debezium, binlog

We have a simple spring boot 3.1 app that wraps debezium. We upgraded to the latest version 2.4.0.Final. Now getting this error after the service was running was running for a few hours:

```
2023-10-05 07:36:54 [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine - Retriable exception thrown, connector will be restarted; errors.max.retries=-1
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be restarted.
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:49)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onEventDeserializationFailure(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1299)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:1101)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient._connect(BinaryLogClient.java:620)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:525)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:932)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Failed to deserialize data of EventHeaderV4{timestamp=1696426677000, eventType=EXT_DELETE_ROWS, serverId=73360770, headerLength=19, dataLength=8155, nextPosition=116155347, flags=0}
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.wrap(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1246)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.EventDataDeserializationException: Failed to deserialize data of EventHeaderV4{timestamp=1696426677000, eventType=EXT_DELETE_ROWS, serverId=73360770, headerLength=19, dataLength=8155, nextPosition=116155347, flags=0}
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.EventDeserializer.deserializeEventData(EventDeserializer.java:341)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.EventDeserializer.nextEvent(EventDeserializer.java:244)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource$1.nextEvent(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:236)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:1088)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.MissingTableMapEventException: No TableMapEventData has been found for table id:137. Usually that means that you have started reading binary log 'within the logical event group' (e.g. from WRITE_ROWS and not proceeding TABLE_MAP
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.AbstractRowsEventDataDeserializer.deserializeRow(AbstractRowsEventDataDeserializer.java:109)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.deserializeRows(DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.java:64)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.deserialize(DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.java:56)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.deserialize(DeleteRowsEventDataDeserializer.java:32)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.EventDeserializer.deserializeEventData(EventDeserializer.java:335)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

The service was unable to heal from this error. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a bug on debezium not processing a particular MySQL binlog message. I'd raise this on their issues tracker.